# What is the earliest manuscript of Amos?

Tags: amos, dating

What are the earliest manuscripts of Book of Amos?

Comment: Question for OP: why??

Answer (score 6):

Amos is represented among the Dead Sea Scrolls, in particular:

- one of the so-called "Minor Prophets" scrolls, [4Q82 = 4QXII<sup>g</sup>](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive/manuscript/4Q82-1);
- [5QAmos = 5Q4](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive/manuscript/5Q4-2); and
- a tiny fragment, purportedly from Cave 4, recently [edited by Emanuel Tov](https://doi.org/10.1163/15685179-12341291).

These are, roughly, [Herodian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herod_the_Great), so first century BC. For some discussion about these manuscripts, see Philippe Guillaume, "[A Reconsideration of Manuscripts Classified as Scrolls of the Twelve Minor Prophets (XII)](http://www.jhsonline.org/Articles/article_77.pdf)", *Journal of Hebrew Scriptures* 7 (2007), article 16.

*Nota bene*: none of these mss is a copy of the complete book. For that, in Hebrew, one would be looking at the at the great medieval codices of the [Masoretic Text](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tags/masoretic-text/info).

Comment: There is also scroll [MUR XII (Mur 88)](http://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/explore-the-archive/manuscript/MUR88-1) discovered at [caves of Wadi Murabba'at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadi_Murabba%27at). This scroll contains the minor prophets to include most of the Book of Amos.

Comment: Thanks for that addition, @Joseph. Perhaps worth adding, too that "the majority of manuscripts discovered at Wadi Murabba'at, as well as texts from Nahal Hever and Nahal Se’elim, date to the Roman period", i.e., post 70 CE (so later than the mss listed above).